# render image from numbers, gather data from database

Tags: image

I have a headache, because i have some text that look like that :

> 1:0_0_63_64_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_5_34_67_99_132_164_194_215_234_253_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_255_253_234_215_194_164_132_99_67_34_5_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_

but much longer

Do anyone know how to convert that kind of text in do image?

Only thing i know that it will be 2d model.